# Area bounded by $f(x)=1/e^{x^2}$ and two lines $x=a, x=3a$

Tags: calculus, integration, area, curves

The area is bounded by $$f(x)=e^{-x^2}$$ and two lines $$x=k$$ and $$x=3k$$
Find an expression for the area including $k$, and determine the value for $k$ which will maximize the area.

I general, you find the area between curves by finding their point(s) on intersection, taking the difference between them and taking the definite integral at the said point(s) - which gives us the integral.

Should I use that the same procedure here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area is simply
$$\int_k^{3k}e^{-x^2}\,dx$$
But the primitive of the integrand isn't elementary. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function. In any case, calculating explicitly the area, **isn't** required. Only the **derivative** is required.

Comment: You don't need to compute the integral. You only need its derivative with respect to $k$ in order to find its maximum value.

Comment: @b00nheT, yes but my point is that the integral **can't** be explicitly calculated. The derivative of $\text{erf}$ is constant$\cdot e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: That is indeed true. But the OP may be tricked into thinking that the problem cannot be solved by hand, which is not the case.

Comment: @b00nheT, the link includes the formula for $\text{erf}'$, but probably you are right.

Comment: @b00nheT, edited for greater clarity.

Answer (score 3):

While $$F(k):=\int_k^{3k}f(x)\,\mathrm dx$$
cannot be expressed elementary, you only need to find $k$ that maximizes $F(k)$ and not the explicit maximal value of $F$. For finding the maximizing $k$, note that
$$F'(k)=3f(3k)-f(k) $$
 (why?) and solve for $F'(k)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

As Martin said, the area is given by
$$A(k):=\int_k^{3k}e^{-x^2}\,dx.$$
To compute the maximum with respect to $k$, we use [differentiation under the integral sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign):

$$A'(k)=3e^{-(3k)^2}-e^{-k^2}=3(e^{-k^2})^9-e^{-k^2}.$$
The function $A(k)$ will attain an extremum at $k_0$ iff $A'(k_0)=0$. Setting $y:=e^{-k^2}$ this happens when 
$$3y^9-y=0\iff y=0\quad \lor \quad y=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt[8]{3}}.$$
But we still need to solve for $k$, and the only possible value of $y$ which admits a solution is $+\frac{1}{\sqrt[8]{3}}$, so:
$$e^{-k^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[8]{3}}\iff-k^2=-\frac{\ln(3)}{8}\iff k=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\ln(3)}{8}}.$$
Of course for the maximum we choose the $+$ sign.